# Starting out with functional equations

Tags: reference-request, functional-equations

I am thinking of starting learning about various functional equations and ways to solve them, any help as to which books could be of help to me?

I have some knowledge about some basic functional equations.

Answer (score 4):

I am going to guess that you are looking for the type of functional equations that are encountered in Olympiad style problems. Engel's Problem solving book is a good training book for potential olympiad students and contains methods to attack olympiad type functional equations. The following [book](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/dynamical+systems/book/978-0-387-34539-0) looks even better but I can not personally verify its quality. Two nice resources to work over a few days to learn or review the basics are [this](http://www.mathsolympiad.org.nz/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/functional-equations.pdf) and [this](http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~olympiad/Training/Algebra/Functional_Equations.pdf). Also, take a look through [the Art of Problem solving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewforum.php?f=3) and use the search function to find functional equations. Or even better, just search username pco's posts, he is a master of functional equations and is constantly posting great solutions.

Comment: Hi, hopefully, you're still active. I just wanted to know if functional equations are any use outside of competition mathematics. Do any actual uni courses teach an applicable form of functional equations that is not just for leisure? (not including differential equations, I know those are useful)