# Good online references for solving functional equations?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, functional-equations

I was wondering what are the main tricks one can try when dealing with a functional equation, like trying values, checking injectivity, surjectivity, bijectivity...

In particular, how is one sure generally to know every function that satisfies a functional equation (that is there are no more)?

What I am asking for are links or reference materials from the internet; but if you have a list, I'd be grateful to read it!

Comment: Or maybe [Starting out with functional equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69936/26369)?

Comment: Oh, great! Thank you